# Densest Graphs with Unique Perfect Matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, examples, perfect-matchings

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, that has a perfect matching $M$, what is the maximal number of edges that $G$ can have without contradicting the uniqueness of $M$?

Are examples of such extremal graphs known?

Comment: You should check out the Gallai-Edmons Decomposition, this follows from that easily, see, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011204.

Comment: I recently found [this paper](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~stolee/Papers/HSWY11-ExtremalGraphs.pdf), that addresses the topic in a more genersl setting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with $2n$ vertices with a unique perfect matching $M$. Choose any $2$ edges from $M$ and consider the $4$ vertices present. In addition to the $2$ edges from the matching there can be at most $2$ more edges if we want the matching to be unique. Thus the number of edges must be less than or equal to $n + 2\binom{n}{2} = n^2$.

This bound can certainly be realized. Let $G_{2n}$ be the graph with vertex set
$$\{x_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\} \cup \{y_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$$ and edge set 
$$\{x_ix_j : 1 \leq i < j \leq n\} \cup \{x_iy_j : 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\}.$$
We see that $G_{2n}$ has $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges. Moreover $\{x_iy_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ and the unique perfect matching in $G_{2n}.$ Notice this is exactly the graph constructed by Wolfgang in his answer (and also alternatively constructed by Yoav Kallus in a comment to Wolfgang's answer). Furthermore Wolfgang asks if $G_{2n}$ is the unique graph on $2n$ vertices with $n^2$ that has a unique perfect matching. We will now show this is the case.

Let $H$ be a graph on $2n$ vertices with $n^2$ edges such that $H$ has a unique perfect matching. Let $\{x_iy_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ be the unique perfect matching in $H$. Let $H_{ij}$ denote the subgraph induced by vertices $\{x_i, y_i, x_j, y_j\}$ for any $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. Then $H_{ij}$ is a graph on $4$ vertices with $4$ edges for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. We know the number of edges in $H_{ij}$ is bounded above by $4$ from our argument for the upper bound, and it must be exactly $4$ to have $n^2$ total edges. In fact each $H_{ij}$ is isomorphic to the graph on vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with edge set $\{12,13,14,34\}$.

**Claim:** Fix $1 \leq i \leq n$. If $\deg_{H_{ij}}(x_i) = 3$ for some $1 \leq j \leq n$, then $\deg_{H_{ik}}(y_i) < 3$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

*Proof)* If $\deg_{H_{ij}}(x_i) = 3$, then $H_{ij}$ has edge set $\{x_iy_i, x_ix_j, x_iy_j, x_jy_j\}$. Assume $\deg_{H_{ik}}(y_i) = 3$ for some $k$, then $H_{ik}$ has edge set $\{x_iy_i, x_ky_i, y_iy_k, x_ky_k\}$. But this contradicts $H$ having a unique perfect matching (check that $H_{ijk}$, which is the subgraph of $H$ induced by vertices $\{x_i,y_i,x_j,y_j,x_k,y_k\}$, would have multiple perfect matchings by considering possible edges in $H_{ik}$). **QED**

Now assume without loss of generality that the vertices are labelled such that $\deg_{H_{ij}}(y_i) < 3$ always (or equivalently, the unique degree $3$ vertex in $H_{ij}$ is always $x_i$ or $x_j$). Define a relation $x_i \prec x_j$ if and only if $x_iy_j$ is an edge in $H$.

**Claim:** $(\{x_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}, \prec)$ is a totally ordered set.

*Proof)* First note either $x_i \prec x_j$ or $x_j \prec x_i$ for any $i,j$ since either $x_i$ or $x_j$ in the degree $3$ vertex in $H_{ij}$. We have $x_i \prec x_i$ since $x_iy_i$ is an edge of $H$. If $x_i \prec x_j$ and $x_j \prec x_i$, then $x_i = x_j$ otherwise the uniqueness of the prefect matching would be contradicted. Finally we verify transitivity. Take $x_i, x_j$ with $x_i \prec x_j$ and $x_j \prec x_k$.  Assume $x_k \prec x_i$, then $H_{ijk}$ has the prefect matching $\{x_iy_j, x_jy_k, x_ky_i\}$ with is a contraction. Thus $x_i \prec x_k$ and $\prec$ is transitive. **QED**

Now this total order on $\{x_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$  describes an isomorphism $H$ to $G_{2n}$ and therefore $G_{2n}$ is the unique graph (up to isomorphism) with $2n$ vertices, $n^2$ edges, and a unique perfect matching.

Answer (score 7):

An easy construction to achieve the bound of $n^2$ edges for $2n$ vertices: embed the $n$ edges $(v_i,w_i)$ of the 1-factor as parallel segments in the plane. To these $n$ edges, add all $\binom n2 $ possible edges $(v_i,w_j)$ with $i<j$ and all $\binom n2 $ edges $(w_i,w_j)$.
For any 1-factor, each $v_i$ must belong to a different edge, from there it is clear that there is a unique one.

Comment: Another simple construction is by recursion: (1) Of the $2n$ vertices, pick two; (2) connect one of them to all $2n-1$ vertices; (3) put the two vertices aside, set $n\leftarrow n-1$ and go back to (1).

Comment: @YoavKallus Yes, the result is the same. BTW I start wondering if the extremal graph is unique!

Comment: @Wolfgang should the comparison "$i<j$" rather be $i\le j$? Currently $v_n$ would not be adjacent to an edge (if I didn't overlook something).

Comment: @ManfredWeis The 1-factor (i=j) is already there. :) And the fact that $v_n$ has degree 1 says it all about unicity of the 1-factor, e.g. via recursion.

Comment: @Wolfgang I do believe there is a unique extremal graph. See my updated answer. Only 5 months later :)